# how to add mergyaPub repository to maven settings.xml

Tags: maven

I am trying to compile an old project at work and one of the artifacts was deleted and moved to EmergyaPub repositor `(http://nexus.emergya.es/nexus/content/repositories/public/)`

When I tried to mvn compile it says it not there.  I assume I have to add this url as a mirror in my settings.xml file, but everything I have tried has failed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.2.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.2.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.2.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <pluginGroups>
        <pluginGroup>org.mortbay.jetty</pluginGroup>
        <pluginGroup>org.apache.tomcat.maven</pluginGroup>
        <pluginGroup>com.frequentis.c4i.tools.maven</pluginGroup>
    </pluginGroups>

  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>admin123</password>
    </server>
  </servers>

  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>central</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <name>central</name>
      <url>http://fdirhel3-frequentis-usa:8081/repository/maven-group/</url>
      <blocked>false</blocked>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
</settings>
```

or
adding this in:

```
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>EmergyaPub</id>
      <mirrorOf>dummy</mirrorOf>
      <name>www.sonatype.com</name>
      <url>http://nexus.emergya.es/nexus/content/repositories/public</url>
      <blocked>false</blocked>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
```

Each fails.  So what do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to get the repository added, so I downloaded the old code from github so I had the jar.  Then following the comments on this page, I found the one that worked for me at the bottom.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project?rq=2

Create a Maven repository in: ${project.basedir}/local-maven-repo.

mkdir local-maven-repo

In the pom file the repository needs to be specified which would take file path as a URL parameter:

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>local-maven-repo</id>
        <url>file:///${project.basedir}/local-maven-repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

Add the JAR file to local repository using "mvn deploy:deploy-file" like so:

mvn deploy:deploy-file \
   -DgroupId=jacksum \
   -DartifactId=jacksum \
   -Dversion=1.7.0 \
   -Durl=file:./local-maven-repo/ \
   -DrepositoryId=local-maven-repo \
   -DupdateReleaseInfo=true \
   -Dfile=./jacksum/jacksum.jar

The will create the follow directory structure:
./local-maven-repo/jacksum/jacksum
    maven-metadata.xml
    maven-metadata.xml.md5
    maven-metadata.xml.sha1
    1.7.0/jacksum-1.7.0.jar
    1.7.0/jacksum-1.7.0.jar.md5
    1.7.0/jacksum-1.7.0.jar.sha1
    1.7.0/jacksum-1.7.0.pom
    1.7.0/jacksum-1.7.0.pom.md5
    1.7.0/jacksum-1.7.0.pom.sha1
```

The old code then compiled and installed ok.

Comment: Could you format your answer so that the codes and explanation texts are distinguishable?